# Make Lambda function execute now, and/or in an hour

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, scheduled-tasks, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to implement an AWS Lambda function that should send an HTTP request. If that request fails (response is anything but status 200) I should wait another hour before retrying (longer that the Lambda stays hot). What the best way to implement this?

What comes to mind is to persist my HTTP request in some way and being able to trigger the Lambda function again in a specified amount of time in case of a persisted HTTP request. But I'm not completely sure which AWS service that would provide that functionality for me. Is SQS an option that can help here?

Or, can I dynamically schedule Lambda execution for this? Note that the request to be retried should be identical to the first one.

Any other suggestions? What's the best practice for this?

(Lambda function is my option. No EC2 or such things are possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly trigger Lambda functions from SQS (at the time of writing, anyhow).

You could potentially handle the non-200 errors by writing the request data (with appropriate timestamp) to a DynamoDB table that's configured for [TTL](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-automatic-item-expiration-with-time-to-live-ttl/). You can use DynamoDB Streams to detect when DynamoDB deletes a record and that can [trigger](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/) a Lambda function from the stream.

This is obviously a roundabout way to achieve what you want but it should be simple to test.

Comment: It's tempting to go this way. But I want to know that my invoke time is as accurate as possible. And this post for instance, say that the deletion is done in the background, after TTL, but no guaranties for how fast: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-manage-dynamodb-items-using-time-to-live-ttl/

Answer (score 0):

As jarmod mentioned, you cannot trigger Lambda functions directly by SQS. But a workaround (one I've used personally) would be to do the following:

If the request fails, push an item to an SQS Delay Queue ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html))

This SQS message will only become visible on the queue after a certain delay (you mentioned an hour).

Then have a second [scheduled](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) lambda function which is triggered by a cron value of a smaller timeframe (I used a minute).

This second function would then scan the SQS queue and if an item is on the queue, call your first Lambda function (either by SNS or with the AWS SDK) to retry it.

PS: Note that you can put data in an SQS item, since you mentioned you needed the lambda functions to be identical you can store your first function's input in here to be reused after an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a closer look at the [AWS Step Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) for this. Basically, Step Functions is a state machine that allows you to execute a Lambda function, i.e. a *task* in each step.

More information can be found if you log in to your AWS Console and choose the "Step Functions" from the "Services" menu. By pressing the [Get Started](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=eu-central-1#/statemachines/create) button, several example implementations of different Step Functions are presented. First, I would take a closer look at the "Choice state" example (to determine wether or not the HTTP request was successful). If not, then proceed with the "Wait state" example.